# Select a default for missing rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table to keep count of the number of visitors on a website.

```
|Day|Visitors|
|1  |2       |
|2  |5       |
|4  |1       |
```

I want to select the number of visitors per day for days 1 to 4, but I also want a value for day 3. Since day 3 is missing, I wonder if it is possible to select all integers in a range, and if the column is missing, a default is to be returned. A simple "SELECT visitors FROM table WHERE day >= 1 AND day <= 4 ORDER By day" query will return "2, 5, 1", but the query I'm looking for will return "2, 5, 0, 1".

Comment: This transformation of data would be much easier to accomplish in the program that is consuming the results of your query. I would either do that, or insert records for missing days and set their values to zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example for your data:

```
select n.n as days, coalesce(visitors, 0) as visitors
from (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4
     ) n left outer join
     t
     on t.days = n.n;
```

You need to fill in all the numbers of days in the `n` subquery.  Perhaps you have another table with sequential numbers which can help with this and other queries.

Answer (score 1):

Use the power of the scripting language that you are using for the website to check for the missing `days` and show `0` for those days

Answer (score 0):

If you REALLY NEED to get this from the database, you can use a table to hold the day numbers and do a LEFT JOIN with it:

```
SELECT coalesce(table.visitors, 0) AS visitors
FROM days_table
LEFT JOIN table ON days_table.day = table.day
WHERE table.day >= 1 AND day <= 4 ORDER By day
```

Comment: I will use php to fill the missing days. This should not be difficult, but I was just wondering if I was underestimating the power of SQL queries...

Comment: Good to know. And is always better to research for better solutions.